# Garbage cleanup on windows phone

Tags: settings, 7.5, storage, cleaning

From a sole user perspective, are there any ways or tools to keep the phone clean and fresh.

I mean people install and remove many apps daily on their phone which must leave a lot of foot prints on the system as we have experienced using windows desktop. Since there is no way to explore the file system, what should one do in regard to system cleanup for windows phone.

If there is no way for this, then is the OS capable enough if handling this thing on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phone is very good at cleaning up after the uninstallation of applications, to the point where if you reinstall them, they think it's a clean install. I believe this is down to the storage system, as no application can directly see any data from another application, and no application can install additional system libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There is no facility for 'purging the phone' after installs and uninstalls.  Users and tools really can't touch the file system at all.  As Rowland says, it just takes care of itself.